# How to implement parallel-search on an unsorted wordlist (like but not; parallel.foreach)

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, parallel-foreach

I am trying to explicitly using multicore techniques to search an **unsorted** wordlist (AAAA -> ZZZZ), the Parallel.Foreach had served my purpose but I need to demo my own solution to University (hence, using threading) and expand it later

e.g.

```
Parallel.ForEach(list, (s) => {
                     if (s[index].Equals(c))
                     { stack(s) }});
```

Output must be: the strings of that list starting with a specific input char c (e.g. 'Q')

Comment: do you want to implement your own version of `Parallel.ForEach` ?

Comment: @IvanKaloyanov oh youre right :D but only to make it explicit :D

Comment: @styx exactly!  to take advantage of MultiCore processor without using PLINQ Parallel.foreach. basically to handle my  specific input : collect strings starting with a desired char in an unsorted wordlist